# split strings containing piping characters

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, awk

I am working with some text containing field-separators which are "||||":

```
substring1||||substring2
```

The substring might also contain whitespaces. I want to split these strings just according to the delimiter "||||", but I couldn't find a proper way to do that.
I tried the following command:

```
echo "substring1||||substring2" | awk '{split($0,a,"||||"); a[2],a[1]}'
```

actually, that command works if I have just one "|" as the separator. but my problem is that I have more than one pipe character.

I also tried

```
a=($(echo "substring1||||substring2" | sed -e "s/||||/\n/g"))
```

It works fine if the substring don't contain whitespaces. but since the substrings might contain whitespaces, they are splitted also on the spaces, which is not desired.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a regular expression as input field separator, like:

```
awk -F'[|]{4}' '{ printf "Field 1 -> %s\nField 2 -> %s\n", $1, $2 }' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
sub string 1||||sub string2
```

It yields:

```
Field 1 -> sub string 1
Field 2 -> sub string2
```

---

**EDIT**: For older `awk` versions that don't accept `{n}` syntax use `-F'[|][|][|][|]'` or `-F'[|]+'` instead, like:

```
awk -c -F'[|]+' '{ printf "Field 1 -> %s\nField2 -> %s\n", $1, $2 }' infile
```

Also adding `--re-interval`, thanks to **blue** for his comment:

```
awk -c --re-interval -F'[|]{4}' '{ printf "Field 1 -> %s\nField2 -> %s\n", $1, $2 }' infile
```

Comment: @Hakim: Perhaps your `awk` version is too old, but you are right. It seems that doesn't accept the `{n}` syntax because I got rid of it with `-F'[|][|][|][|]'` and it worked. Give a try.

Comment: Thanks Birei, this one works fine. It is also possible to use -F'[|]+' instead of repeating it 4 times.

Comment: @Hakim: Yes. That also works. I've edited the answer to add both options.

Comment: Is there any way to store the results in arrays instead of printing them? Actually I want to have the first column in one array, and the second column in another array. And once the processing finished, store them in 2 separate files.

Comment: in gawk you have to add option `--re-interval` to use multipliers like  `{4}`

Comment: well in newer versions of gawk, it is enabled by default. Sauce: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options

Comment: Is there any way to store the results in arrays instead of printing them? Actually I want to have the first column in one array, and the second column in another array. And once the processing finished, store them in 2 separate files.

Comment: @Hakim: Save them in an array: `IFS=$'\n'; arr2=($(cat infile | awk -c --re-interval -F'[|]{4}' '{ printf "%s\n%s", $1, $2 }'))`

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU awk` you can describe what a field is using `FPAT` instead of describing what the field separator is:

```
$ echo "substring1||||substring2" | awk '{print $1,$2}' FPAT='[^|]+' OFS='\n'
substring1
substring2
```

Comment: +1. I didn't know about this awk feature. But this would split a field with an embedded '|', or '||', or '|||'

Answer (score 2):

The pattern used by `split` in `awk` is actually regex, so `||||` might actually be 4 alternation operator instead of 4 literal vertical bars (I'm not sure because under certain conditions, `|` can be a literal vertical bar.

To match vertical bars, use `\|` or `[|]`. So for what you want, you can do this

```
awk '{ split($0, a, /\|+/); print a[2],a[1]}' file
```

Note I used `/.../` (regex constant) to enclose the pattern instead of quotes (dynamic regex). Some details about the difference in [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps).

---

If you want to write column 1 to one file, and column 2 to another file, you can do it all in `awk` (I'm using Birei's way because it is more concise).

```
awk -F'[|]+' '{c1 = c1 $1 "\n"; c2 = c2 $2 "\n"} END {printf c1 >"file1"; printf c2 >"file2"}' input_file
```

This appends column 1 entries to `c1` separated by newline, column 2 to `c2`. Then print both to separate files after processing the input file.

Notes:

1. Concatenation works in `awk` by placing the strings side by side.
2. I used `printf` which doesn't append a newline, because we already have an extra newline at the end of `c1` and `c2`.
3. All the horizontal spacing in the awk script except between `printf` and its argument is optional.

---

Sidenote: the value of `-F` is actually a dynamic regex, so the equivalent of `'[|]+'` is `'\\|+'`.

Answer (score -3):

Try using sed and tr ... see if it helps !!

**Input.txt**

```
sub string 1||||sub string 2
            or
 substring1||||substring2
```

**Code**

```
  sed 's/||*/%~%/g' Input.txt| tr "%~%" '\n' | sed '/^$/d'
```

**Note**

Use any expression like "%~%" .... Any expression(like which I have used)  which does not appear to your text file... and replace that using sed and tr...

Comment: I can not replace piping characters with semicolon, because the substrings might contain semicolon and it might lead in wrong splitting.

Comment: Updated ... just replace ';' with other expressions which does not appear to your text file....